# Scrapy response.xpath how to get the number output

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to get in Scrapy a numeric value instead of text. Please see in the code "result-number-lg btn-number-details" - the output 0156 numeric value. How do I do it?

I have try

```
response.xpath('//span[contains(@data-prize-type,"1")]/text()').getall()
```

the output is {FirstPrize} instead of 0156.

[0156](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd7Hp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq349.png)

[FirstPrize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J9QB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded dynamically by javascript. That's why to grab the desired data you have  to use an automation tool something like selenium. Here I use selenium and getting the desired output as follows:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.magnum4d.my/en/results"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(15)

values =driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="result-number-lg btn-number-details"]')

for v in values:
    print(v.text)
```

Output:

```
0156
0590
6894
5691
4449
2699
7762
2968
9727
```

Comment: Can you share the url or update your question?

Comment: this url https://www.magnum4d.my/en/results

Comment: @GIN, I've updated